# .NET class Polygon

Tags: .net, f#, polygon

I need to work with concave polygons. Basically I need to know their width and height, a method to know if a point is inside the polygon and possibly x,y coordinates of the rectangle that circumscribes it (so I can easily implement drag&drop function). What can I use?

I could define a custom Polygon type, but I would have problems to implement the "Contains" classic method, considering polygons are concave.

Suggests?

Comment: Have you included the System.windows.shapes namespace? What error are you getting when you try to instantiate a new polygon? "doesn't work" is too vague.

Comment: when I try to instantiate the polygon: "Type Polygon not defined"
when I try to include System.Windows.Shapes: "namespace 'Shapes' not defined"

Comment: The `System.Windows.Shapes.Polygon` is not a mathematical model of a polygon. Rather, it is a UI element in WPF. You may be able to use it as a mathematical model, but that's not what it was designed for. Would you use a `Panel` as a rectangle?

Comment: Understood, so it doesn't exist a Polygon class like the Rectangle one. Damn, are you talking to me that I have to create myself a Polygon type? No idea how to implement the Contains method, considering it's a concave one...

Comment: Sounds to me like you want [`System.Drawing.Region`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.region.aspx)...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath`:

```
GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
path.AddPolygon(new[] {new Point(0,1), new Point(5,8), new Point(2,4)});

bool isPointInPolygon = path.IsVisible(4, 1);
```

Comment: Yeah, it works but the GraphicsPath hasn't its x,y coordinates, so polygon ones are not relative to the path but absolute. This is going to complicate a drag&drop operation, even considering I have to save all these data in a XML file. Surely it's more easy than update all polygon coordinates each time.
I can't even inherit the class to define a new one for my aims...

Comment: @FrankLioty, to deal with the absolute coordinates, can't you just translate your test point in the opposite direction to your graphics path's rendering translation and use that point for the hit test against your absolutely defined graphics path?

Comment: not understood. BTW I was implementing drag&drop method changing all coordinates vertex values but it doesn't make a move. I got them with the PathPoints property.

Comment: @FrankLioty, if you don't want to extract the points and offset them each time you do a drag/drop, you can use `GraphicsPath.Transform` to perform a translation tranformation on the path - `Matrix m = new Matrix();m.Translate(offsetX,offsetY);path.Transform(m);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Shape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms604615) and in particolar the [`Polygon` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.polygon), interact with these object is particularly simple, but if you are dealing with thousands of edges I suggest to use the [`DrawingVisual` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingvisual.aspx), a visual object that can be used to render vector graphics on the screen, and its `RenderOpen` method.

`DrawingVisual` does not provide event handling, so if with `Shape` you can use events to interact with edges, with `DrawingVisual` you need to implement [Hit-Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hit-testing).

With a `Polygon` to know [`Height`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.height) and [`Width`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.width) simply use the element properties.

If you want to check if a `Point` is inside your polygon you can use the [`InputHitTest` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.inputhittest) or esle the [`VisualTreeHelper.HitTest` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608752.aspx):

```
let res = yourPolygon.InputHitTest(new Point(x, y))
let res = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(yourPolygon, new Point(x, y))
```

In conclusion: if you seek an elegant method to check if a point is inside a polygon take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/218081/995246) answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are some nice routines to find out if a point is within a polygon. Check out http://www.softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0103/algorithm_0103.htm